# Passing a returned string into another string and using it in an if statement

Tags: php, sql, function, return

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
            require_once 'Membership.php';
    $membership = New Membership();
    $AccountType = $membership->is_Account($currUser);
    if ($AccountType == 'S') {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $AccountType;
        echo '</li>';
    }
   ?>
```

Which calls upon a different document membership.php with a function that does this:

```
function is_Account($currUser){
    //Find out if user is a buyer or a seller
    $mysql = New Mysql();
    $mysql->get_Account($currUser); 
}
```

Which for organisational reasons - goes to a document (this bit works, as other functions work successfully) that does this:

```
function get_Account($currUser) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }       
    $queryAcct = "SELECT Id
            FROM Users
            WHERE Username = '$currUser'
            LIMIT 1";
    if ($Result = $mysqli->query($queryAcct)){
        if (!$Result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $row = $Result->fetch_assoc();
            return $row["Id"];
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

So - that last function has an issue. I want to use the Id returned so that for example if it is 1, I display that content pertaining to Id 1 (multiple people will have that Id number as it is a tier system).

Basically - I have no idea why it isnt returning the Id to the original bit of code. I assume i've done something wrong. I just don't know how to fix it.

Echoing $row["Id"] will work so I know that bit is fine and its not an sql issue. But that isnt what I want to do.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would like to have a word with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the value from `get_Account()` in your `is_Account()` function:

```
return $mysql->get_Account($currUser);
```

Comment: They joy of stackoverflow. I muddled over that for an hour and a half. Still learning! Thank you :) It'll let me pick your answer in 6 minutes